# NPM Multer returning no response

Tags: node.js, npm, multer

I am trying to upload a file using `npm multer`. The issue is multer is returning no response, not even error. I tried to create the common function for whole application for file upload. **I have all (777) permission to my folder as well.**

My sample code is.

```
var uploadFile = require('../../utilities/common').uploadFile;
exports.uploadVehicle    = function (req, res) {
    console.log('\nUploading File');
    console.log(dirPath.vehicleFarm);
    uploadFile(dirPath.vehicleFarm, 'csvFile', function (err) {
        console.log('\tError:');
        console.log(err);
        if (err)
            return res.status(err.status || 400).json({code: err.status || 400, message: err.message || 'Unable to process request.'});
        var data = req.body;
        console.log(data.csvFile);
        res.status(200).json({status: 200, message: 'File saved successfully'});
    });
};
```

The `uploadFile` function in common file is mentioned like this.

```
var multer         = require('multer');
var path           = require('path');
var fs             = require('fs');
var filePath       = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
var storage        = function (inputDir, fieldName) {
    console.log('Input from storage to path - ' + inputDir);
    console.log(filePath + '/uploads/' + inputDir);
    return multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, filePath + '/uploads/' + inputDir);
        },
        filename   : function (req, file, cb) {
            var dateTimeStamp   = Date.now();
            req.body[fieldName] = file.fieldname + '-' + dateTimeStamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1];
            console.log(req.body[fieldName]);
            cb(null, req.body[fieldName]);
        }
    });
};
exports.uploadFile = function (inputDir, fieldName) {
    return multer({storage: storage(inputDir, fieldName)}).single(fieldName);
};
```

Input path is also valid even the folder also exists Path is - `/home/sony/Desktop/node/all/db/uploads/tempCSV/vehicleFarm/`

Where I have mistaken? How would I trace if file uploads fails as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since with target to create single function with dynamic parameters for directory and filename. Here the issue is resolved.**

```
var dirPath                  = require('./directory-path').dirPath;
var multer                   = require('multer');
var path                     = require('path');
var fs                       = require('fs');
var filePath                 = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
exports.uploadFileToPath     = function (directory, fieldName) {
    this.uploadFile = multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                console.log('In Destination - ');
                cb(null, filePath + '/uploads/' + directory);
            },
            filename   : function (req, file, cb) {
                var dateTimeStamp   = Date.now();
                req.body[fieldName] = file.fieldname + '-' + dateTimeStamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1];
                console.log(req.body[fieldName]);
                cb(null, req.body[fieldName]);
            }
        })
    }).single(fieldName);
};
```

Where I need to call this function, I instantiated it like

```
var common     = require('../../utilities/common');

var uploadVehicle = new common.uploadFileToPath(dirPath.vehicleFarm, 'csvFile');
uploadVehicle.uploadFile(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('\tError:');
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(err.status || 400).json({code: err.status || 400, message: err.message || 'Unable to process request.'});
    }
    var data = req.body;
    console.log('File Name --- ' + data.csvFile);
    //if (data.length === 0)
    //  return callback({status: 400, message: 'Bad request. No record found.'});
    res.status(200).json({status: 200, message: 'File saved successfully'});
});
```

Now its properly returning response in error case also. Files are uploading to dynamic path passed in params.

Answer (score 0):

@Sankalp, I checked the code and made it work, but not with all logic to format the filename (please, do re-implement that later).

As you did not include here the code from the form you are submitting, I think its important to say it must have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in it, otherwise it doesn't work.

Also, the input with `type="file"` must have the `id` and `name` attributes with value as the one passed for the `.single()` function in NodeJS code. It works as an identifier, so it's better not be dynamic (or you will have to dynamically set it in your HTML too).

The NodeJS code is very straight forward and I think there's no problem with it.

The resulted working code is here:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' id='csv_file' name='csv_file' value='Choose file' />
    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
```

**NodeJS** *(I've used Express to test it)*

```
var storageFile = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var even = Date.now() % 2;
        if (even == 0) {
            console.log("Save in dir_a");
            callback(null, 'files/dir_a');
        } else {
            console.log("Save in dir_b");
            callback(null, 'files/dir_b');
        }
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log('Setting the filename.');
        var filename = "File_" + Date.now().toString().substring(0, 11) + ".csv";
        cb(null, filename);
    }
});

var uploadFile = multer({storage: storageFile }).single('csv_file');

app.post('/file', function(req, res) {
    console.log('-------------------------------------------');
    console.log('>>> POST - Submitted page: ' + req.url + ' <<<');
    console.log('-------------------------------------------');

    uploadFile(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('<h1>Error to upload file ' + err + '</h1>');
        } else {
            res.send('<h1>File ' + req.file.filename + ' successfully uploaded</h1>');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with the solution you provided. I had pre written function same in form you mentioned and it works. But what I amend is, I passed dynamic directory  path and filename(current version), and it stopped working. My front end code is same to what you have written.

Comment: @Sankalp, with the modifications to make it work with a dynamic path, are you getting any error? Are you sure the file is trying to be saved in the correct path? Another option would be to have 2 (or as many as you want) different `diskStorage()`, one for each path, then you control inside the app.post() which one you want to use.

Comment: I have everything Ok, path is valid even the folder exists. But their is no response from multer function. Not even error. This is the reason I can't debug. What options you are mentioning for 'diskstorage', let's check that also. But I do expect response from multer function either error or true or else.

Comment: @Sankalp, I edited the answer and inserted the code I used to show Multer saving in different folders. What I checked is that you don't have any other information from *request* (value from fields in the form) before all upload process is done. If you can define the folder to save the file not relying on request information, then it's fine (just work in your logic). If you need the request information, I would let Multer download the file to the folder and after that, according to your condition, I'd move it to the right folder.

Comment: I had same code written what you have edited now. Even I implemented same code in the morning before reading your comment as it was working before. I manipulated it according to requirement so that for the whole application it become modularize. I wish to pass just 2 options that are input directory and file name that need to be saved. You have rectified problem correctly that my request information is empty. This code works absolutely fine. But my expectation is to work it for the dynamic path and filename passed in the function call.

Comment: I am still confused why it doesn't work with the return as I have mentioned in sample code earlier. Please do a favour to rectify it, I have also posted on issues of multer github, so I get some fine solution. Contribute to the solution. I want the same multer function for whole app and a different set of directories to all my calls.